# rally_api query for getting defects based on iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rally

I am using rally_api gem in Ruby. Could any one suggest me how to write query that gets all the defects under a particular iteration?

```
require 'rally_api'
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.version = "1.0"

config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username]   = "mvcmxb"
config[:password]   = "kjkjk"
config[:workspace]  = "Persons"
config[:project]    = "Business he does"
config[:headers]    = headers 

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

test_query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
test_query.type = "defect"
test_query.fetch = true

results = @rally.find(test_query)
```

Comment: please provide solution what you try.

Comment: I need to fetch defects only for a particular iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code example when defects are queried by iteration and their description is updated. You may either query by iteration name:

```
query.query_string = "(Iteration.Name = \"i10\")"
```

or iteration ref:

```
query.query_string="(Iteration = /iteration/13589769934)"
```

Names are not unique, but the query is also bound by the project:

```
rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)
query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :defect  
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,Iteration,Description"
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/12352608219.js" } 
query.project_scope_up = false
query.project_scope_down = false
query.order = "Name Asc"
#query.query_string = "(Iteration.Name = \"i10\")"
query.query_string="(Iteration = /iteration/13589769934)"

results = rally.find(query)

results.each do |d|
    puts "FormattedID: #{d["FormattedID"]}, Iteration: #{d["Iteration"]["Name"]}"
    d.read
    fieldUpdates = { "Description" => "bad defect"}
    d.update(fieldUpdates)
end
```